# Convert Sqoop sql-timestamp column to actual datetime

Tags: sql-server, sqoop

Sqoop import we are facing issue to convert the sql-timestamp column to actual datetime.

In one of the SQL Server table we have following stamp columns and this is the reliable increment column and while converting in to datetime we are getting the conversion error.

```
      stamp  =0x00000001B59E3B57
              0x00000001B59E3B58
              0x00000001B59E3B59
              0x00000001B59E3B5A
```

But I get an error:

> CAST (stamp AS DATETIME) AS Load_time
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Comment: are you sure that is a `datetime` value ?